# Two NSManagedObjectContexts observing each other's NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have view controller A with a table view using a NSFetchedResultsController, based on the main context and a view controller B that handles downloads from server and save them in the database working on a second context, let's call it editing context.
The main context observes NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification, and merges chenges when the editing context saves.

When I delete a cell from view controller A, the NSFetchedResultsController saves changes on the main context. In B, if I try to download again the object deleted in A, I got an error when saving context.

I have solved this this way, but I really don't know if it is a good approach:
I have made the editing context observe the main one, so when I delete something on the main context, the other one merges changes. So main context and editing context are observing each other. 
Can it cause problems?

Comment: What is the error you get when saving?